# F12 IE Developer Tools and Emulation (new window persistence)

Tags: internet-explorer, developer-tools

very quick question.

A colleague is looking to test something in IE10 mode, using a newer version of IE. When he sets the Emulation to IE10, and clicks on a link with a _blank target, a new copy of IE opens and it loses the emulation setting.

Is there a way to add persistence, so that any new windows would open with the pre-set emulation mode?

thanks

Comment: Use [`x-ua-compatible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) meta tag within the page you're loading to a new window. It's not very reliable even for testing purposes though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you download our newest IE Developer Channel bits.  See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/06/16/announcing-internet-explorer-developer-channel.aspx

As referenced [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn743687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#emulation_changes), you can persist emulation settings with this update.  Enjoy and let me know if you have any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The F12 update in developer channel mentioned by Kirk is now released via IE 11 August update.

Make sure that you have got the latest IE update, and you can start using this and many other new features. Read [more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/14/announcing-new-f12-dev-tools-features-in-august-update.aspx).